# Número por extenso não é exibido corretamente em caso de unidade e dezena

Tags: php

Quando é digitado três números o programa exibe o nome por extenso de maneira correta, porém quando é digitado 2 ou 1 número ele exibe na ordem errada, exemplo: digitei 51, ele retorna:

```
Unidade = 
Dezena = 1
Centena = 5

Unidade = 
Dezena = Décimo
Centena = Quingentésimo
```

ou seja, eu queria que ele pegasse só a dezena mais a unidade, no caso do exemplo: Quinquagésimo Primeiro

Segue o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Portfolio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="outro.php">
        Numero: <input type="text" name="numero">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="Exibir">
    </form>
</body>
</html>


<?php
    // receber o número digitado
    $num = $_POST["numero"];

    echo "Número digitado: $num<br>";

    /*if ($num > 1000) {
        echo "Digite um número até mil";
        return false;
    } 

    if ($num === 1000) {
        echo "Milésimo";
    }*/

    $unidade = substr($num,2,1); // criar um array(vetor) pra cada unidade
    $dezena  = substr($num,1,1);
    $centena = substr($num,0,1);

    echo "<br>Unidade = $unidade";
    echo "<br>Dezena  = $dezena";
    echo "<br>Centena = $centena";

    // Vetor de Unidade
    $aUnidade[0] = "Zero";
    $aUnidade[1] = "Primeiro";
    $aUnidade[2] = "Segundo";
    $aUnidade[3] = "Terceiro";
    $aUnidade[4] = "Quarto";
    $aUnidade[5] = "Quinto";
    $aUnidade[6] = "Sexto";
    $aUnidade[7] = "Sétimo";
    $aUnidade[8] = "Oitavo";
    $aUnidade[9] = "Nono";

    // Vetor de Dezena
    $aDezena[0] = "";
    $aDezena[1] = "Décimo";
    $aDezena[2] = "Vigésimo";
    $aDezena[3] = "Trigésimo";
    $aDezena[4] = "Quadragésimo";
    $aDezena[5] = "Quinquagésimo";
    $aDezena[6] = "Sexagésimo";
    $aDezena[7] = "Septuagésimo ";
    $aDezena[8] = "Octogésimo ";
    $aDezena[9] = "Nonagésimo";

    // Vetor de Centena
    $aCentena[0] = "";
    $aCentena[1] = "Centésimo";
    $aCentena[2] = "Ducentésimo ";
    $aCentena[3] = "Tricentésimo ";
    $aCentena[4] = "Quadringentésimo ";
    $aCentena[5] = "Quingentésimo ";
    $aCentena[6] = "Sexcentésimo ";
    $aCentena[7] = "Septingentésimo ";
    $aCentena[8] = "Octingentésimo ";
    $aCentena[9] = "Nongentésimo ";

    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "Unidade = $aUnidade[$unidade]<br>";
    echo "Dezena  = $aDezena[$dezena]<br>";
    echo "Centena = $aCentena[$centena]<br>";

    echo "<br>";

    if (strlen($num) == 3) {
        echo "$aCentena[$centena] $aDezena[$dezena] $aUnidade[$unidade]";
    } elseif (strlen($num) == 2) {
        echo "$aDezena[$dezena] $aUnidade[$unidade]";
    } elseif (strlen($num) == 1) {
        echo "$aDezena[$dezena]";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Acho que terá que melhorar bem esse algoritmo, a geração do extenso é bem mais complicada que isso.

Comment: Pois é cara, eu percebi isso olhando em fóruns, o código para gerar o extenso é bem mais complexo, o problema é que é bem complicado para um iniciante

Comment: Relaciondas: [Como transformar dígitos numéricos em números por extenso?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5945/91) e [Como gerar um valor por extenso em português no MS Office Excel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/371/91)

Comment: Com a classe `NumberFormatter` da `intl` é possível fazer isso em inglês: https://ideone.com/ZzuSVW. Talvez com a instalação de algum arquivo adicional seja possível também em português.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz uma `function` para isso, vê se te ajuda. Segue:

```
function num_ordem($num=1,$masc_fem='M')
{ 

if (strlen($num) == 3) {
    $unidade = substr($num,2,1); // criar um array(vetor) pra cada unidade
    $dezena  = substr($num,1,1);
    $centena = substr($num,0,1);
} elseif (strlen($num) == 2) {
    $unidade = substr($num,1,1); // criar um array(vetor) pra cada unidade
    $dezena  = substr($num,0,1);
} elseif (strlen($num) == 1) {
    $unidade = substr($num,0,1); // criar um array(vetor) pra cada unidade
}

// Vetor de Unidade
if ($masc_fem=='M')$cons='o'; else $cons='a';
$aUnidade[0] = "Zer".$cons;
$aUnidade[1] = "Primeir".$cons;
$aUnidade[2] = "Segund".$cons;
$aUnidade[3] = "Terceir".$cons;
$aUnidade[4] = "Quart".$cons;
$aUnidade[5] = "Quint".$cons;
$aUnidade[6] = "Sext".$cons;
$aUnidade[7] = "Sétim".$cons;
$aUnidade[8] = "Oitav".$cons;
$aUnidade[9] = "Non".$cons;

// Vetor de Dezena
$aDezena[0] = "";
$aDezena[1] = "Décim".$cons;
$aDezena[2] = "Vigésim".$cons;
$aDezena[3] = "Trigésim".$cons;
$aDezena[4] = "Quadragésim".$cons;
$aDezena[5] = "Quinquagésim".$cons;
$aDezena[6] = "Sexagésim".$cons;
$aDezena[7] = "Septuagésim".$cons." ";
$aDezena[8] = "Octogésim".$cons." ";
$aDezena[9] = "Nonagésim".$cons;

// Vetor de Centena
$aCentena[0] = "";
$aCentena[1] = "Centésim".$cons;
$aCentena[2] = "Ducentésim".$cons." ";
$aCentena[3] = "Tricentésim".$cons." ";
$aCentena[4] = "Quadringentésim".$cons." ";
$aCentena[5] = "Quingentésim".$cons." ";
$aCentena[6] = "Sexcentésim".$cons." ";
$aCentena[7] = "Septingentésim".$cons." ";
$aCentena[8] = "Octingentésim".$cons." ";
$aCentena[9] = "Nongentésim".$cons." ";

if (strlen($num) == 3) {
    return "$aCentena[$centena] $aDezena[$dezena] $aUnidade[$unidade]";
} elseif (strlen($num) == 2) {
    return "$aDezena[$dezena] $aUnidade[$unidade]";
} elseif (strlen($num) == 1) {
    return "$aUnidade[$unidade]";
}

}
```